# Mixture of romaji and hiragana in NHK "Meet and Speak"

Tags: orthography, kana, rōmaji

In the NHK program "Meet and Speak", the phrases they use have a mixture of hiragana and romaji. Not as in hiragana on one line, and romaji underneath, but individual words being composed of the two, such as "すmimaせn".

[image: Example image]

What is the purpose of this mixture? Is is supposed to indicate pitch accent? Alternatively, is romaji used for hiragana that the program has not yet taught?

Comment: Just my guess, but during these episodes they introduce new hiragana to be learned. Possibly the romaji are for kana not yet introduced at the time of this episode? To me it just seems confusing though.

Comment: I've seen this show on NHK World a few times and @user3169 is right. They only use hiragana for the hiragana the viewer is meant to have learned from the show at that time - your 'alternate explanation' ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your alternate hunch is correct I expect, as I've seen it [elsewhere](http://www.tofugu.com/reviews/japanese-from-zero-1-progressive-edition/) (referred to as 'progressive', there, but I'm not sure if that's a universal term).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here's an example of only showing the kana being learnt.

In this screenshot, all the hiragana has presumably been learnt, and the "k" line of katakana is being learnt, hence "カ" appearing as katakana, and "ta" and "na" appearing as romaji.

[image]